# InputAction.CallbackContext functions not showing up in inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up the new input system in my unity project.

I have created my Input actions and attached a player input component to my game object.

Ive then attached a script to the GO.

I'm trying to use the unity events.

Ive dragged my script (i also tested dragging the GO itself) from the GO into on of my input actions but when I try and select my function it doesnt appear in the list.

PlayerInputHandler.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMoveInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMoveInput");
    }

    void OnJumpInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJumpInput");
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my component]

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think you can't have non basic params like `InputAction.CallbackContext context` in an event arguement. You'd either write a basic signature (ints, strings, floats etc) or instantiate an instance of the input class e.g. `MyPlayerInputScript myScript = new MyPlayerInputScript`, then you can access it's members like `if (myScript.Player.SomeMethod.GetFloat() < 2` etc. It's odd at first but you get used to it :)

Comment: See here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HowDoI.html

Comment: It must be `public`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It turns out, the handler method must not be private.

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnMoveInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMoveInput");
    }

    public void OnJumpInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJumpInput");
    }
}
```